# How to make website available on google search using ngrok?

Tags: python, url, apk, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I tried to make my website offline and available on google search but I am using ngrok with is the url is variable and always change when run the program. how can I make the website url fixed by using ngrok coding? I need the fixed url because need to make an apk for mobile phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to pay for ngrok's premium plans to get that functionality. If you already own a domain, you can easily achieve the same -

- Install nginx on the server hosting your content
  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/
  This process changes based on your operating system. Make sure to start the nginx daemon after installation.
- Configure nginx
  Enter the `sites-enabled` directory (usually  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/) and edit the file named `default`

Paste the following

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  server_name <your_domain.com>;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<your_port>;
  }

  proxy_redirect     off;
  # These are the critical headers needed by uvicorn to honor HTTPS in url_for :
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 # These are just some other headers you may find useful
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

}
```

Replace `<your_domain.com>` with the name of your domain, and `<your_port>` with your localhost port number.

Restart the nginx daemon, and add an 'A' Record on your domain pointing to the Public IP Address of your web server.

When you visit `<your_domain.com>`, you'll see your localhost app being available to the outside internet.

You need a domain for this. It's cheaper than ngrok, you can buy them from websites like godaddy.com and namecheap.com.

Comment: thank you so much. it is very helpful for me who are new in this field.

Comment: Sorry for asking the coding u give is use for window os?